# laravel modify how the password is checked in the authentication process

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.2.

I would like to be able to change a parameter in the .env file like PASSWORD_VALIDATION=...

This could be either LARAVEL or PERSONAL.

If it is LARAVEL then it would use the standard Laravel authentication method with users and passwords in the db. But if I use PERSONAL, I would like that it uses a function I have created that will check if the email address is in the database then verify the password provided with the Active Directory in my company.

I looked at the various files and I can see I have:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
```

In there, I can see:

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

In this file:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php
```

It uses

```
use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers {
        AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
        AuthenticatesUsers::getGuard insteadof RegistersUsers;
```

So I can see in the file

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

My function to be changed which is:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->login($request);
    }
```

I have tried to copy this one in my file app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php but it doesn't change anything if I modify what is inside it...

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Why do you want to modify the password check flow?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out why, it seems that in my routes, it is pointing to @login and not to @postLogin hence any modification applied to the function postLogin wouldn't do anything